# What QML Charts Type choose for histogram

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I need to use QML charts for displays histogram. But I do not know how I will be drowing this histogram (by points or by formulas)
[image]

What best QML Charts Type choose for this case?

Comment: Check the [Qml Charts Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-qmlchart-example.html) and choose the one that suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put together a simple histogram using [ChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html) with a [StackedBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-stackedbarchart-example.html):

[image]

```
import QtCharts 2.15


ChartView {
    id: chartView
    anchors.fill: parent

    property var binCategoryNames: [ [1,3], [4,5] ]
    property var binCategoryCount: [6, 4]

    title: "Bins for Random Number Generation"
    legend.visible: false
    legend.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
    antialiasing: true

    StackedBarSeries {
        axisX: BarCategoryAxis {
            categories: binCategoryNames
        }

        axisY: ValueAxis {
            min: 0
            max: 10
            labelFormat: "%i"
        }

        BarSet {
            label: "";
            values: binCategoryCount
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more information on the [QML Charts Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlchart-example.html) page.